# How does this algorithm converge?

Tags: kernel-smoothing

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation, we have this formula for the optimal bandwidth for a kernel density estimator.

[image]

Note that we need $R(f'')$ which is unknown.

An algorithm is thus

guess $h_0 \rightarrow$ calculate $R(f'')$ from the resulting kernel density estimate $\rightarrow$ use the formula to calculate $h_1$ $\rightarrow $ calculate $R(f'')$ from the new density $\rightarrow$ use formula to calculate $h_2 \rightarrow$ ...

My question is, how does this algorithm even converge?

Assume that $h_1 < h_0$. But a lower bandwidth means a less smooth kernel. Then $h_1$ will lead to a kernel density estimate with a higher $R(f'')$. But then $h_2$ will be lower, due to the formula. But then the next $R(f'')$ will be even bigger, so $h_3$ will be even lower, etc.

So how do people use this algorithm for convergence? It clearly seems to converge to zero?